# Chrome browser opening to MyStart Incredibar

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, malware

When I first open chrome, it is always opening to the page: http://mystart.incredibar.com/mb188?a=6OyOmJk7dX&i=26

This only happens on first opening. Starting a new window gets me the new tab page, hiting the home button bring me to my chosen home page. It is NOT saving the tabs from my last session.

This first stared happening when some shady installer decided I wanted a chrome extension called "incredible" and installed it for me.

I have already removed the extention, restored my homepage and search settings, and scowered my system for related files. But the problem persists on initial startup.

My theory is that is somehow hijacked the normal function of the feature that recalls the last session.

I have also tried re-installing chrome over the top, without uninstalling.

Is there any way (short of total uninstall-reinstall) that I can restore normal function?

Comment: For the curious, the shady installer was for a kit designed to help me root me Droid 4. Very disappointed, hacker community, you're better then that.

Comment: You've said you've restored homepage and search settings, but don't mention Chrome's "On Start-up" setting - have you checked this as well?  This may still have the old incredibar URL set.

Comment: @PJC put that in an answer and you get the bounty. I did not know that that setting existed.

Comment: looks like I missed the bounty window...

Comment: @PJC Sorry about that. You do get an accept and an up vote though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my original comment -- As well as the Home Page, and the Search Settings, Google Chrome has an "On Start-up" setting.

You can change this in Settings -> On Start-up, since this probably still has the old Incredibar URL set.

Answer (score 0):

This should completely remove MyStart Incredibar:

(Before following these steps, make sure you have deleted the `MyStart Incredibar` extension and an extension called `New Tab Page` or something along those lines, if it's in the extensions list. It's actually MyStart Incredibar)

1. Go to the start menu, click on `Computer`.
2. In the search box, type in `mystart`.
3. When you get results, simply right-click on them and delete them all. You may have to refresh, for your own peace of mind to make sure they have all been deleted.
4. Repeat, searching also for: `incredibar`, `coolyou`, `conduit` and `perion`.

---

I have also found this guide: [Remove MyStart by IncrediBar (Uninstall Guide)](http://deletemalware.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/remove-mystart-by-incredibar-uninstall.html). It includes screenshots and instructions for all major web browsers: Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.

Associated MyStart by IncrediBar files and registry values:

```
Files:
======
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\GottenAppsContextMenu.xml
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\Incredibar-Games_ENToolbarHelper.exe
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\ldrtbIncr.dll
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\OtherAppsContextMenu.xml
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\prxtbIncr.dll
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\SharedAppsContextMenu.xml
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\tbIncr.dll
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\toolbar.cfg
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\ToolbarContextMenu.xml
C:\Program Files\Incredibar-Games_EN\uninstall.exe


Registry values:
================
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Conduit\RevertSettings "http://mystart.Incredibar.com?a=1ex6GUYANIc&i=38"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\IM\38 "PPD"
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ImInstaller\Incredibar
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Incredibar
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Incredibar-Games_EN
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main StartPage "http://mystart.Incredibar.com?a=1ex6GUYANIc&i=38"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Conduit\Toolbars "Incredibar-Games EN Toolbar"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Incredibar-Games_EN\toolbar
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar "Incredibar-Games EN Toolbar"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Incredibar-Games EN Toolbar
```

Comment: Searching found some left over cruft, but none on chrome. I already removed the extension and restored my search and home page. And yet, it still opens to the incredibar page when I first start Chrome.

Comment: @MatthewScouten Did you look at the linked guide? Maybe it will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did. It told me nothing that I hadn't figured out myself. Did you just Google the name for me? I come to superuser for expert assistance after I have ALREADY done the obvious.

Comment: @MatthewScouten Well you should mention in your question *exactly* what you've already done. If you've already tried to delete the files and the registry values from your computer, please mention it.